# Proper electrical safety of PoE Equipment

Tags: networking, power-over-ethernet

Working on a residential install in my own home. I have a small closet network setup in my office with an unshielded patch panel, a PoE-capable switch, and a rack-mounted surge protector. The switch is powered by the surge protector, which is plugged into a properly installed/grounded electrical outlet.

I would like to run an outdoor WAP to connect my house to an outbuilding (a barn) in a point-to-point configuration some 100 feet away from the house so that I can install IP Cameras for animal security/monitoring, and to supply general internet there for music/streaming. I will mount the WAP on the outside of the house and run a single CAT6 UTP cable from the WAP to my switch. No injector will be used as the switch can provide adequate power. It should look something like:

```
Barn                                             House
PoE Switch ---- WAP <LOS open air> WAP ---- PoE Switch
```

The question that comes into play is the safety of each of the components given their outdoor installation. For one, each AP will be mounted outside, but not at the highest point of either building. A single UTP CAT6 cable will connect them to their associated networks.

1. Do I need signal arresters at any point in the install? Namely between the WAPs and the switches?
2. Is the grounding provided by the PoE switch enough to satisfy the grounding requirements that would normally come with using an injector?
3. Can I wire the WAP through the unshielded patch panel or should PoE devices be connected directly to the switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Can't hurt, but make sure you get ones that are compatible with PoE. Some are not. If you don't use them worst case you just fry the Ap and the switch, possibly the surge protector and other equipment connected to the same switch. If you have lightning rods on the buildings (not unusual on a farm) I wouldn't bother at all.
2. Yes. Should be on any decent PoE switch.
3. Either would work. Doesn't really matter for PoE.